# Calculating square root

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture, system-verilog

I write code to calculate perfect square of number, but I am not getting proper output. I take input `b` and regs `a`, `d`. Firstly, I put `1` in `d`, then square it and store in `a`. Then compare with input - if it is not satisfied then increment `d`. But at output I am getting is `square = XXXX`.

My code:

```
module square_root(b,clk,square);

input [3:0] b;
input clk;
output [3:0]square;
reg[3:0]a,square;
reg[2:0] d;

initial
  begin
    d<=3'b001;
  end

always@(clk)
  begin
    a<=d*d;
    if(a==b)
      square<=a;
    else
      d<=d+1;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: You're missing a reset signal for `d`. Unless you initialize flip-flops with known values, you'll get `X`s.

Comment: I assume `a` looks ok, then you never meet the condition `a==b` to set square. NB without a complete flag how will you know the results has been calculated, and if it is calculating square root you want `square<=d`.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
initial
begin
  d<=3'b001;
end
```

TO

```
initial
begin
  d=3'b001;
end
```

Test Bench:

```
module TB_SQT;
  reg [3:0]b;
  reg clk;
  wire [3:0]square;

  square_root SQT(b,clk,square);

  initial
  begin
    clk=0;
    b=9;
  end

  always
  #1 clk=!clk;

endmodule
```

Comment: You're missing a reset signal.

Comment: @Tudor yeah...I know...but I just pointed the mistake in OPs code

Answer (score 0):

```
module Sqrt(
  input clk,
  input [3:0]in,
  output reg [3:0]out);

  reg [3:0]temp=1;

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    if((temp*temp)==in)
      out<=temp;
    else
      temp<=temp+1;
  end
endmodule
```

Test Bench:

```
module TB_Sqrt;
  reg clk;
  reg [3:0]in;
  wire [3:0]out;

  Sqrt SQRT(clk,in,out);

  initial
  begin
    clk=0;
    in=9;
  end

  always
  #2 clk=!clk;

endmodule
```

Not probably the best code...but hey

Comment: You're missing a reset signal. In real life, the statement `reg[3:0] temp = 1` doesn't have any meaning. The assignment would be ignored by a synthesis tool.

Comment: @Tudor I believe that this is an acceptable way for FPGA initial values to be written. Your correct for ASIC where it would be ignored.

Comment: @Morgan I had no idea. Still, without a reset signal you can't really go back to your initial state (aside from unplugging the device, I guess), so the usefulness of not having one is rather limited.

Comment: @Tudor, I agree, I guess in most set-ups power cycling is used to reset things. My understanding is that async resets are quite expensive (not that common) on fpga devices. although sync rests can be used. To complicate matters recommendations and usage vary from vendor to vendor.

Comment: @Tudor yeah that is quite obvious. I just slammed it together to show the OP. **reg[3:0] temp = 1** is perfectly normal.